# Can I fly to Spain from Italy as a non-EU citizen if my name has changed?

Tags: schengen, italy, spain, italian-residents, permesso-di-soggiorno

I changed my name on my passport, and now it's a little different from the name on my *permesso di soggiorno*. I have a letter from the embassy proving my new name. I went to my local [*questura*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/italian-english/questura) to try to get my *permesso* updated with my new name, but I was told I can only change the name when my *permesso* expires. In the meantime, can I travel by air with my documents?

Answer (score 3):

I have a feeling that the Questura gave you wrong information. Having dug a bit on governmental sites, [it seems that you are not allowed to have differing personal information on your passport and your residence permit in Italy](http://www.prefettura.it/roma/contenuti/Stranieri_e_anagrafe-4938.htm):

> 2. E' importante sapere che:
>
> [...]
>
> - Tutti i dati anagrafici (nome e cognome, luogo e data di nascita, cittadinanza) contenuti nel passaporto e nel permesso di soggiorno devono essere assolutamente coincidenti.

Which translates to:

> 2. It is important to know that:
>
> [...]
>
> - All personal data (name and surname, place and date of birth, citizenship) contained in the passport and in the residence permit must absolutely coincide.

Now, according to the regulation, [you can report all personal information changes to the authorities so that your residence permit gets updated](https://www.comune.modena.it/servizi/anagrafe-e-stato-civile/variazioni/variazione-dati-anagrafici-di-cittadini-non-italiani):

> ## Variazione dati anagrafici di cittadini non italiani
>
> I cittadini non italiani nati all'estero possono richiedere la rettifica di dati anagrafici che possono riguardare: nome, cognome, sesso, luogo, data di nascita, territorio di nascita e cittadinanza. La richiesta può essere fatta per se stessi e per i figli minori.
>
> ### Modalità di richiesta
>
> [...]
>
> Il giorno dell'appuntamento occorre portare [il modulo di richiesta compilato](https://www.comune.modena.it/documenti-e-dati/modulistica/anagrafe-e-stato-civile/variazioni-anagrafiche-e-di-stato-civile/variazione-di-dati-anagrafici-di-cittadini-non-italiani) e i seguenti documenti (originali e fotocopia):
>
> - documento di identità valido per l'espatrio indicante le nuove generalità
>   titolo di soggiorno valido o scaduto con ricevuta di rinnovo (solo per cittadini non comunitari)
> - codice fiscale/i (allegare tutti i codici fiscali eventualmente posseduti dal richiedente)
> - passaporto con generalità vecchie (se in possesso)
> - carta di identità con vecchie generalità (se in possesso)
>
> Se la variazione riguarda le generalità  (nome/cognome, sesso, luogo di nascita, data di nascita o territorio di nascita) è necessario presentare  inoltre:
>
> - un documento che attesti che il cittadino ha cambiato generalità rilasciato dall'autorità del paese di provenienza come ad esempio: attestazione consolare di concordanza che attesti la variazione di generalità se necessario legalizzato in Prefettura (vedi esempio), certificato di matrimonio che attesti l'acquisizione del cognome del coniuge a seguito di matrimonio, attestazione consolare che attesti la variazione di generalità a seguito di eventi specifici.
>   I documenti provenienti dall'estero dovranno essere in regola con le norme sulla traduzione e legalizzazione dei certificati esteri (vedi nota* sui documenti rilasciati da autorità estere)

Which translates to:

> ## Change in personal data of non-Italian citizens
>
> Non-Italian citizens born abroad can request the rectification of personal data which may concern: name, surname, sex, place, date of birth, territory of birth and citizenship. The request can be made for oneself and for minor children.
>
> ### How to request
>
> [...]
>
> On the day of the appointment, you must bring the completed application form and the following documents (original and photocopy):
>
> - valid identity document for expatriation indicating the new generalities valid or expired residence permit with renewal receipt (only for non-EU citizens)
> - tax code (s) (attach all tax codes possibly owned by the applicant)
> - passport with old details (if in possession)
> - identity card with old details (if in possession)
>
> If the variation concerns the personal details (name / surname, sex, place of birth, date of birth or territory of birth) it is also necessary to submit:
>
> - a document certifying that the citizen has changed personal details issued by the authority of the country of origin such as: consular attestation of concordance attesting to the variation of generality if necessary legalized in the Prefecture (see example), marriage certificate attesting to the acquisition of the spouse's surname following marriage, consular attestation attesting to the change in generality following specific events. Documents from abroad must comply with the rules on the translation and legalization of foreign certificates (see note * on documents issued by foreign authorities)

Having said this, it is reasonable to conclude that you may not be able to travel with mismatched documents, as you should not be able to hold mismatched documents. To solve your problem I would request an updated residence permit.

Answer (score 1):

The policies may different among-st different airlines. The easiest way is to call directly to the airlines that you're planning to travel with and ask the situation.